# What is this part on a 1997 Chevy Suburban (4WD) [picture inside]?

Tags: suspension, part-identification, suburban

We have a 1997 Chevy Suburban, 4WD. *Occasionally*, when turning right (usually from a dead stop) there is a distinct "clunk" sound that comes from below the drivers side floorboard (with an equally distinct "clunk" feel in the floorboard). I used to have a Nissan Maxima that had some bad control arm bushings, and it feels pretty similar to the Maxima when I'd go over bumps and the control arm would bang around in the stiff bushings. Recently there's been a similar (but different) sound that happens when turning left - especially if it's a hard left.

I'm pretty sure this is the part that's causing at least one of those noises, and I looked on AutoZone's website/repair guides, but I couldn't find something definitive.

What is this part called?

(Up close - the bushing is pretty much gone)

[image: what is this part?]

A little farther out. I have the steering wheel cranked all the way to the right and took this from the rear of the drivers-side front wheel-well.
[image: what is this part?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sway bar link.  The usual symptoms related to this wear are a medium pitch clunk when going over small bumps and lessened body roll control on cornering.

Comment: Come on, Fred, we all know a Suburban doesn't start with any body roll control on cornering! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  I do not often drive vehicles with this primitive suspension type but when I do I wish for multiple sway bars.